# Is there a way to prevent a part of a string to be printed out?

Tags: c#, string

I need to store some data in the end of a string, but the rest I want the user to be able to see it except for the end. Is that makes sense or can I do it somehow (in C#)?

Comment: What do you mean by able to see ?? You need to develop your question

Comment: Could you explain your requirement in more detail? As it stands, your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: In many cases you can add `\0` to make string's tail invisible: `MyTextBox.Text = "I can see this" + "\0" + "but not that.";`

Comment: You could create a class that has all your data and then override the ToString() method to print it.

Comment: Create your own class to clearly communicate intent. Do not use "clever tricks" to tweak types into unclear behaviour.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Thanks for the hint, I'll definitely try that :)

Comment: And to all the others, thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a special String class?

```
public class MySpecialString
{
    private string _userEntered;

    public string VisibleText 
    {   
       get
       {
         return _userEntered;
       }
       set
       {
          _userEntered = value;
           //set your added text  value here...
          AddedText = "&123";  //example
       }
     }
    public string AddedText {get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return VisibleText;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions:

First:

Make the string as long as the width of an A4 paper and then concatenate the to-be-hidden string. The width of a A4 paper is 21 cm.

Second:

Write a printer application which will print out the text for you. Then, inside this program, you can concatenate your to-be-hidden string separated by three dollar sign or some unique string. E.g.: "SeeableText.$$$text-to-be-hidden".

After this, you can easily define what part of your text would you like to be printed by using the String.Split("$$$") method.